# Consolidate multiple SharePoint lists into one using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I have a requirement, where I have multiple lists having data that I need to consolidate into one single list using Power Automate.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to merge multiple lists into one list using Power Automate.

As a workaround, we could merge multiple SharePoint Lists to one Excel file, then create a new list from excel.

My simple test for your reference:

List A:

[image]

List B:

[image]

Note that there is a filter to avoid duplicate rows in excel, in my case, the filter column is **Title**.

Flow steps:

Pic1:

[image]
Pic2:

[image]

Pic3:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Lastly, create a list form excel as shown below:

[image]

[image]